# Photos too large

Tags: camera

I have Galaxy Xcover and when I take a photo of 2.3 resolution and try to send it to contact in text message, it says "Photo is too large. Packing up".

Is there a way to send a picture that large or do I have to use smaller resolution while sending them?

Answer (score 2):

You're limited by the network's MMS capability.  Most carriers won't allow multimedia messages larger than 300 kilobytes (and thus most messaging apps won't even let you try to send a message larger than that), so the image needs to be shrunk to fit under that file size limbo stick.

If you want to send a larger picture, you'll need to send it via a different method, such as an email attachment or a picture messaging service like Snapchat.